# How to remove circular reference from entity framework core

Tags: json.net, entity-framework-core

Web Api Core, Entity Framework Core

**Situation** - Many to many relationship.  A, Join, B.  Join has Id references to both A and B.  A has collection for Joins.  B has collection for Joins.

**Goal** - Get A with Joins with B - and no further.

**Problem** - I get A with Joins with B with the same singular Join back (in a collection).  This is happening on the Entity Framework end.  I believe EFCore is being clever and automatically putting that reference back in for me with the data it has.  This would be nice, except I am returning this as Json to a client.  The Json serialiser detects a circular reference and then omits it (by design).  So my result is:

```js
{ 
  // A stuff, 
  "joins": [{
    "B": {
      // B stuff, 
      "joins":[]
    }
  }]
}
```

I would like the empty joins collection to be null, so the Json serialiser drops it.  Setting the collection to null doesn't work.

```
foreach (A a in query)
{
    foreach (Join join in a.Joins)
    {
        join.B.Joins = null;
    }
}
```

Although during the loop it appears to be setting the value to null, as soon as I escape it the references are back again.

Thank you for any and all help!

-- Note --
Later on I would like to be able to get B with Joins with A.  So I cannot solve this by stopping all serialisation of Joins.A.

Comment: There are sooo many questions in this area. Are you sure none of them covers yours?

Comment: how to stop entity framework automatically reassigning references - 0
entity framework core change data after load - nothing relevant
entity framework core results wont change - 0
entity framework core circular references - leads me to this post.

I'm happy to be corrected but so far I haven't found anything.
- sorry for formatting, it doesn't like new lines.

Answer (score 0):

I answered it by mistake while chasing another issue.

I was under the impression that enumerating the query forced the lazy load to run - since you can actually see data through it.  When I forced my query into a ToList() everything worked as expected.  I don't understand how a foreach doesn't throw an exception on an unloaded query, or why the visual studio debugger allows you to step through, seeing data, but then lazy loads the results of the query again later, but that's what seems to have happened.

I've been on this for two days, then one hour after finally posting online I solve it.  Typical.

Comment: I don't get it.. How did you resolve EF Core not attaching references to main entity if you didn't want them in first place? Have same issue while serializing to json.

Answer (score -2):

To Avoid Circular Reference using Entityframework in dotnet core

```
public​​ void​​ ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

 ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​​​​​services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts => { ​​ 
   opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
  opts.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

 ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​​​ });

 ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​ ​​​​ }
```

Thanks

Comment: This causes a StackOverflowException for me.

Comment: Your answer is another question's answer dude, you just miss it.

Comment: How would that look like in .netcore 3+ ?